# Does the polarity of this crystal matter?

Tags: crystal

I am using TXC 7B 16.0 mghz crystal for my design. I just received photo proofs from my PCB assembly house and it appears they soldered this crystal 180.0 degrees reversed.

https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=887-1104-1-ND[image: diagram]

Edit:
the real [datasheet](http://www.txccorp.com/download/products/quartz_crystals/2015TXC_7B_19.pdf)

Comment: I don't see any polarity.

Comment: What specification did you give for the package orientation? Or would it just look better with the label the other way round?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the polarity does not matter.

Crystals do not have a polarity.

Watch out with Crystal **oscillators** in a similar housing though (also 4 pins) as their polarity does matter.

But since this is a crystal only (no oscillator) polarity does not matter. It will work mounted either way. I speak from experience with similar crystals from the same manufacturer.